# Flattened code creates a generator object?

Tags: python

I'm not understanding why this code isn't working. As nested statements, it works just fine. When I attempt to flatten it - I get the error: `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1068b8660>]`

This is the code as nested statements:

```
with open ('file.txt','r') as file:
   content = file.readlines()
   for line in content:
       if re.match('(?!word)',line):
           print(line)
```

Once I flatten the code, I get the error.

```
with open ('file.txt','r') as file:
   content = file.readlines()
   for line in ( [ line for line in content if re.match('(?!word)',line)) ]:
       print(line)
```

What am I missing in this flattened code? It is creating a list of lists somehow?

Comment: Your brackets (`()` and `[]`) don't seem to match.

Comment: `for line in [line for line in file if re.match('(?!word)', line)]:` No need to define `content` if you don't need it.

Comment: Side-note: Excise `.readlines()` from your code. It's thoroughly pointless, here, and in 99% of the code that uses it. `for line in file:` would work just fine, and wouldn't pointlessly and eagerly create a temporary `list`, requiring memory proportionate to input file size; the lazy loop without `.readlines()` requires memory proportionate to the longest line in the file, no more, and can begin processing immediately instead of waiting for the whole file to be loaded and split into lines.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions work when I fixed the brackets in the second version:

`for line in [line for line in file if re.match('(?!word)',line)]:`

Comment: Try replacing `content` with `file` the variable declared with your `with` statement. See explanation by @shadowranger above for why.

Comment: You're correct. I was lazy and just answered the question. Wasn't going for the extra credit :) Answer edited